# Add Full Query to PHP Session Variable?

Tags: php, mysql, security, session-variables

I've never thought of doing this before, and am unsure of the risks. It's a one time session for each page, replaced by the next page visited.

What's the security risk of doing something like the following? If any?

```
$_SESSION['somename'] = "SELECT `something` FROM `table` WHERE `something`='blah'";
```

Is this a safe method, if not, what's a safer method to store a one time query that will be replaced?

It's probably safer to store queries within a temp mysql table. But I want to avoid additional mysql calls.

Comment: well it is just a string like any other, but i dont see the point. why would the query not be in the page?

Comment: I would not do it. You are giving away a table name that if you did not properly protect against sql injection - I can now try to DROP it. Why risk it?

Comment: ajax remote files, read session query. Query is never the same. Async provides to much readable information on what is being sent.

Comment: ^^^ no idea what that is suppose to mean

Comment: I would store the query in the file that's going to execute it.

Comment: You don't see the point, so I was explaining in a simplistic way, sorry. The point of storing the query, is to be able to pass the query to any remote file which can be called with ajax. But using Ajax post or get, would allow the information to be read easily. My thought on sessions, is the session may not be able to be read.

Comment: ok again, store the query in the file that your calling via ajax

Comment: The query would never be the same - this is a site that has thousands of visitors per minute. Each query, would be slightly different depending on the visitors request. Hence, ajax file cannot store the query. The ajax file will always be the same, the query however, would not be.

Comment: parse the variables you need via ajax to build the query, not the whole thing.

Comment: It's the only option I was thinking would be available, without storing the whole query. But for this case, I'm trying to avoid building the query again. The initial query has already been called, developed, and then displays information to the user with a limit such as 25-100 rows of data. However, storing the query without the limit, allowing user to download all information at once via click of a button ( producing ajax call to a single file that produces the download ). Passing the query, without building the query again would save mass amounts of resources. Some extremely heavy queries.

Comment: The resources used by creating a query string should be negligible. It's running the query that takes the vast majority of the resources, in which case you aren't saving any meaningful amount of time, just adding more insecurity

Comment: can only answer based on the information provided, if you want to change that, im done.

Comment: Dragon,you said "dont see the point. why would query not be in the page"- You didn't answer on the information, instead you question with not understanding why. The question was "is it safe". The why doesn't matter. It's just how it works. Speed of the application is important. It takes 3-30 seconds on a 16CPU server, to build the query, with some sql calls needed for building too, based on data. mysql returns info, which finishes query building. Don't ask "why"- why doesnt matter. 1000 similar builds per minute. To repeat it a second time, can be saved by passing the query without rebuilding.

Comment: *why* really does matter. Many people ask how to do X with out knowing the problem they are trying to solve would be better done via Y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a safe way to set variable with PHP due to the potential of exposing table names that can potentially be DROPPED via SQL injection. Now, session variables are stored on the server and can not be accessed by the browser. However, why introduce a bad habit that could cause someone less savvy on your dev team to use that to set a cookie? Then you have a large problem that started out being benign.  It is better to just place data in your PHP session variables that act as a user identifier.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too harmful (see below), but it's bad practice.

DB queries are the data/model layer, session management is an entirely different topic. You would do yourself a huge favor in [keeping those separate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Also, if you need to cache something, you should cache *results*, not queries. You can, however, make sure that the result is tied to the user by adding an identifier to the result.

For example, you could store a DB query result in an array in Memcached, where the array key would be the user ID.

If you worry about performance of MySQL calls, you should look into normalization and proper indexing.

One note on potential harm: Session data are stored in the filesystem or (seldomly) in memory. On shared hosting systems, there may or may not be measures implemented that prevent other users from reading your session data. On the other hand, your PHP source code is also readable in clear text, and usually has the same permissions, so there's no additional attack vector. A real security threat would be introduced if others could *write* to your session data. But I hope that there are no such setups on the machines of serious hosting businesses.